# ssis smtp mail task /connection ,how to mention the port number if the port number is not 25

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio, ssis, smtp

It has benn understood that the smtp mail task does not work if the port number is not 25.So found some script to do the work from the link

http://englestone.blogspot.co.uk/2008/05/ssis-send-mail-task-change-smtp-port.html

when modified as per my needs it shows 
"SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated"

question is how to add the secure connection section on this vb code
   or
is this error is ue to authentication then the code corresponding to authentication is correct?

Please find the script

```
Public Sub Main()
        Dim myHtmlMessage As MailMessage
        Dim mySmtpClient As SmtpClient



        myHtmlMessage = New MailMessage("sender@s.com", "receiver@s.com", "subject", "body")
        mySmtpClient = New SmtpClient("send.company.net")
        mySmtpClient.Port = 587
        mySmtpClient.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials("sender@s.net", "sender email pwd")




        mySmtpClient.Send(myHtmlMessage)
     Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
    End Sub
```

Any Vb.net/smtp/ expert please reply

Comment: Check my blog entry here for a few hints for dotnet code and smtp.  You don't have to use all the code but you can see a few port settings/situations.      http://granadacoder.wordpress.com/2006/02/08/smarter-emailsmtp-setup-with-dotnet-configuration-sections-1-1-and-2-0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure your SmtpClient to use ssl like:

```
mySmtpClient.EnableSsl = true
```

this should do the trick.

EDIT:
To use the correct credentials use:

```
mySmtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("yourusername", "yourpassword")
```

Comment: mySmtpClient.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials("sender@s.net", "sender email pwd") this line of code has been written as mySmtpClient.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials

Comment: So if i understand you, you changed the Credentials to CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials ? If yes, the Credentials for the SMTP server has to match the Credentials of the user who is executing the application. "As the  DefaultNetworkCredentials represents the authentication credentials for the current security context in which the application is running."[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.credentialcache.defaultnetworkcredentials%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) See Remarks.

Comment: this is giging a syntax error mySmtpClient.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials("sender@s.net", "sender email pwd") ...so how can i assign the username and password ?can i give mySmtpClient.Credentials ="Emailpwd" .sorry i am a beginner in VB

Comment: how to give my own credentials,instead of the default network credentials

Comment: Dim value As NetworkCredential

value =new NetworkCredential("username","pwd")..after adding this code this is working fine thank#